# How to write a program to solve this?

Tags: python

Suppose you are given a list of some numbers. The list can be of any length. Your friend asked you to find the average of the 4th last number, the 2nd last number and the highest number in the list. On the other hand, another friend of yours wanted to know the length of the list and the list of the first half elements. In this case, if the total number of elements in the list is n odd, then n-1 is asked to list the first half of the list of elements.

For example : if a=[1,2,3,4,5,6] is a list of numbers.The 4th last number,the 2nd last number and the highest number in the list are 3,5,6....so the average of 3,5,6 is 4.67....the length of this list is 6 and the list of the first half elements is [1,2,3].

How can i do that in python?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] for your issue, including _code_ for what you've tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts

Answer (score 0):

You should try it by yourself but you can start with this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
fourthLast = a[-4] # output -> 3
secondLast = a[-2] # output -> 5
highest = max(a)   # output -> 6
avg = (fourthLast+secondLast+highest)/3 # output -> 4.66
firstHalf = a[:len(a)//2] # output -> [1,2,3]
```

You can do the same thing by wrapping all the logic into a function and use this function as many times you want without replicating the logic again again just pass you list to the function and get your desired result.

```
def applyStats(listOfIntegers):
    fourthLast = listOfIntegers[-4] # output -> 3
    secondLast = listOfIntegers[-2] # output -> 5
    highest = max(listOfIntegers)   # output -> 6
    avg = (fourthLast+secondLast+highest)/3 # output -> 4.66
    firstHalf = listOfIntegers[:len(listOfIntegers)//2] # output -> [1,2,3]
    print("Average of fourth,second and highest is: %.2f" % avg)
    print("First Half of list is:", firstHalf)

myList = [1,2,30,10,5,6,0.1,9]
applyStats(myList)
```

Comment: Thank you but i want a program that will work for every list automatically @Sheri

Comment: what do you mean by 'for every list automatically'? Could you explain

Comment: that code actualy work for every list, you just change the `a` with your desired list

Comment: like the problems of hackerrank ...your algorithm pass the sample test as well as it will pass other test automatically @Sheri

Comment: @TanvirAhmed you can replace the above list with your any desired list, this solution will work for every list

Answer (score 0):

To find the mean of the numbers:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] # this can have any numbers u want
print(sum([lst[-4],lst[-2], max(lst)])/3)
```

The `lst[-4]` and `let[-2]` are backward indexed and div by 2 cuz we wanna find mean for two numbers.
For finding the greatest value in the list:

```
print(max(lst))
```

For length of list:

```
print(len(lst))
```

For the half-list:

```
print(lst[:len(lst)//2])
```

P.S.: u should probably go through the official [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/) and try out the examples, they're pretty easy.